# Node.js with fs.readFile not able to render file content via http

Tags: node.js

I'm learning node.js but am struggling with the `fs.readFile` function in my simple web server code (demo.js below). If I access `http://localhost:8001/demo.html` I get no data back in the browser, but if I access '/' or any other file name I see the "hello world' or 404 pages as expected.

I have included the content of demo.html and the node console output where the log messages suggest that the readFile is reading the file OK, but I get nothing in the browser and don't see the 'Got here D' log message.

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious but can't see what. Any help would be appreciated!

demo.js code:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            break;
        case '/demo.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error,data){
                console.log("error: " + error);
                console.log("data: " + data);
                if (error){
                    console.log("Got here A");
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("oops problem loading this page - 404");
                }   
                else{
                    console.log("Got here B");
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data);
                }
            });
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Got here C");
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("oops this page doesn't exist - 404");
            break;
    }
    response.end();
    console.log("Got here D");
});

server.listen(8001);
```

demo.html:

```
<html>
<body>This is my demo page</body>
</html>
```

node console output:

```
C:\code\Node>node demo.js
Connection
Got here D
error: null
data: <html>
<body>This is my demo page</body>
</html>

Got here B
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem lies in the position of the `response.end()` call.

`fs.readFile` is an *asynchronous function*; like all functions in node related to *I/O*. This means that the reading of the file is done in a *background* process and when the data is available your defined *callback* function is called with the result.

Node continues to execute your code after `fs.readFile`, which results in `response.end()` being called before your *callback* function builds the *response*.

To fix this you have to move the `response.end()` call into the cases like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            response.end();
            break;
        case '/demo.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error,data){
                console.log("error: " + error);
                console.log("data: " + data);
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("oops problem loading this page - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data);
                }

                response.end();
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("oops this page doesn't exist - 404");
            response.end();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! It's obvious once you pointed it out. I can see now why they talk about 'callback hell'! Thank you!!